# Intersection_inserter was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to calculate the overlap area between two ellipses. I am approximating the ellipses with polygons now and I have found an example that apparently used an old version of `Boost.Geometry`, as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817282/boost-geometry-intersection-inserterpolygon-2d-does-not-work). From the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440768/initializing-a-polygon-in-boostgeometry/2137031#2137031),  I can see that this is an old example as well, since some of the header files are not there in v1.53.
I have replaced those with:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/c_array.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/multi.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
```

and also added this code:

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double,
boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> point_2d;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_2d> polygon_2d;
```

and almost everything works. The only problem is with this:

```
polygon_2d poly, poly2;   
typedef std::vector<polygon_2d > polygon_list;
polygon_list v;
intersection_inserter<polygon_2d >(poly2, poly, std::back_inserter(v));
```

I am getting an error:

```
intersection_inserter was not declared in this scope
expected primary expression before '>' token
```

The documentation of boost on the matter [here](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/group__intersection.html) is from 2009, so I guess it does not apply anymore... Their example is written the same as mine, as far as I can tell. I have found the place on the header file `intersection.hpp` where intersection_inserter is defined but I cannot make heads or tails of it...

I am getting the same error both in VS2012 in win7 and Qt 4.7.4 in Linux Mint 14. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any reference to `intersection_inserter` in the current boost documentation. Perhaps this functionality has been removed?

It seems that the "official" way to calculate intersections in `boost::geometry` is through the `intersection` function, as documented (with example) [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html)